# FileReader readAsArrayBuffer is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm really confused about this. The readAsArrayBuffer is returning this error on old version of FireFox, 4.0 and 5.0. Even if Mozilla's dev website has mentioned this is supported on FireFox 3.6+

```
files.forEach(function(f) {
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    var r = new FileReader();
    var blobslice = File.prototype.slice || File.prototype.mozSlice || File.prototype.webkitSlice;
    var hash = md5.create();
    var chunksize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;

    end = chunksize - 1;

    if (end > (f.size - 1)) {
        end = (f.size - 1);
    }

    r.addEventListener('loadend', function(e) {
        if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
        hash.update(e.target.result);

        if (end != (f.size - 1)) {
            start = end + 1;
            end += chunksize;

            if (end > (f.size - 1)) {
                end = (f.size - 1);
            }

            var blob = blobslice.call(f, start, end + 1);
            r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
        } else {
            console.log(hash.hex());
        }
      }
    }, false);

    var blob = blobslice.call(f, start, end + 1);
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  } else {
    alert('Browser is not supported to upload files');
  }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong here or those browsers don't support this at all?